# Convert a list of strings and lists into a list of chars and lists?

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list of strings and variables. For example:

`['oz_', A, 'ab']`, where A is a list and I don't want anything to happen to it.

And I want to convert it in:

`['o','z','_', A, 'a', 'b']`

`A` is a list, so I don't want anything to change it. How can I do this?

Comment: The list contains references to objects. Given just the list, you can't tell if those references came from variables or string literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obligatory one-liner:

```
>>> A = []
>>> seq = ['oz_', A, 'ab']

>>> [value for values in seq
...  for value in (values if isinstance(values, str)
...                else [values])]
['o', 'z', '_', [], 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for answer like this.

Answer (score 4):

**Updated** now that we know A shall not be altered.

```
A = []
seq = ['oz_', A, 'ab']

res = []
for elt in seq:
    if isinstance(elt, str):
        for e in list(elt):
            res.append(e)
    else:
        res.append(elt)
print(res)
```

output:

```
['o', 'z', '_', [], 'a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to iterate over each element and turn it into a list if it's a string, but otherwise leave it as a variable and append it.

```
source = ['oz_', A, 'ab']
result = []

for name in source:
    if isinstance(name, str):
        result += name
    else:
        result.append(name)
```

Note: Use `isinstance(name, basetring)` for Python2.x if you want to account for other types of string like unicode.

Answer (score 3):

If the complete elements of the list were strings, You could use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) , it takes an iterable (like list/tuple, etc) and then for each iterable element inside it, it creates a new list consisting of the elements of those inner iterables (which in this case are strings). Example -

```
In [5]: lst = ['oz_', 'A', 'ab']

In [6]: list(chain.from_iterable(lst))
Out[6]: ['o', 'z', '_', 'A', 'a', 'b']
```

---

As given in the updated question -

> A is a list, so I don't want anything to change it.

You can do this (similar to what @SuperBiasedMan is suggesting) (For Python 3.x) -

```
In [14]: lst = ['oz_', 'A', 'ab',[1,2,3]]

In [15]: ret = []

In [18]: for i in lst:
   ....:     if isinstance(i, str):
   ....:         ret.extend(i)
   ....:     else:
   ....:         ret.append(i)
   ....:

In [19]: ret
Out[19]: ['o', 'z', '_', 'A', 'a', 'b', [1, 2, 3]]
```

You can use `basestring` in Python 2.x to account for both unicode as well as normal strings.

Please also note, the above method does not check whether a particular object in the list came from variable or not, it just breaks strings up into characters and for all other types it keeps it as it is.

Answer (score 3):

For converting a list of strings into a list of character, I see two approaches:

1. Either use a list comprehension, containing literally each char for each of the strings:

   ```
   >>> lst = ['oz_', 'A', 'ab']
   >>> [char for string in lst for char in string]
   ['o', 'z', '_', 'A', 'a', 'b']
   ```
2. Or `join` the strings and turn the result into a list:

   ```
   >>> list(''.join(lst))
   ['o', 'z', '_', 'A', 'a', 'b']
   ```

---

If `A` is meant to be a variable and you want to preserve it, things get more tricky. If `A` is a string, then that's just not possible, as `A` will get evaluated and is then *indistinguishable* from the other strings. If it is something else, then you will have to differentiate between the two types:

```
>>> joined = []
>>> for x in lst:
...     joined += x if isinstance(x, str) else [x] # +x extends, +[x] appends
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [a for a in ''.join(['oz_', 'A', 'ab'])]
['o', 'z', '_', 'A', 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: @JamesSmith OP wants to preserve `A` as a variable, not a string.

Comment: Then just do `A = [a for a in ''.join(['oz_', 'A', 'ab'])]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chain.from_iterable` either way, you just need to wrap your non strings in a list:

```
from itertools import chain

out = list(chain.from_iterable([sub] if not isinstance(sub, str) else sub for sub in l))
```